# How shall I block Content of the Url from Android app programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, security, browser

I just want to make an Android Locking app.My Motive is like that my Android App wants to block some installed apps and for browser like (Chrome,UC browser), I wants to block only URL of The particular site and all the Adult Content site or features.
[image] 
***Means if someone open the browser that time it would show "website not Found"***

When Installing on first time,the android app will take permission from device in Setting -> **Accessibility** and **Usage Access Mode** or **the necessary permission**.

What is the step by step android code for blocking url feature?

Comment: you got any solution for this ?